# SQL: revoking permissions from public in master

Tags: sql-server

By default SQL grants execute permission on stored to public and also select to some table and views in Master to public...I am not 100% sure about this... What is the implication if we have to remove the select privileges on those objects from Public on Master?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have given any account that needs explicit permissions to those objects (views/procedures) you should see no issues. The issue I usually see after altering PUBLIC role permissions is applications that assume the permissions are there instead of just giving explicit permissions to them.

You will find that some Microsoft documentation states to not alter the PUBLIC  role permissions. I work with the IASE database checklist and the permissions given to the PUBLIC role is one of the first things we have to remove/revoke. I always keep the script handy to restore the permissions if needed.

**EDIT**
Query to find public permissions that I use sometimes:

```
SELECT o.name AS [Object], p.permission_name AS [Type]
FROM sys.all_objects o
INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions p ON o.object_id = p.major_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals u ON u.principal_ID = p.grantee_principal_id
WHERE u.name = 'public'
```

Comment: is there an easy way to find out what privileges does public have?

Comment: added it to the my post

Comment: I have found that removing the SELECT rights from master can cause trouble with Job Agent jobs unless the Job Agent service account is given SELECT rights to various objects in master.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it for everything.

Most lock down scripts [remove or DENY rights selectivity](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/Tools/LockdownScript/tabid/64/Default.aspx). SQL Server 2005+ is better than older versions too (the script is for SQL Server 2000)

Just run SQL profiler and see what runs when a standard user opens a database using SSMS. For example, [spt_values is heavily used but undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4273723/27535). Saying that, this will only affect developers or such (db_owner at most, never sysadmin) anyway. End users shouldn't use SSMS